# Problems with innerHTML array

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple "like counter": every time I click on a span element with class `heart-icon`, the content inside the span `like-counts` should increase by 1.

But I got stuck with returning the elements collection  when I get an array of innerHTML content inside spans.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```js
var hearts = document.getElementsByClassName("os-list__icon");
for (var i = 0; i < hearts.length; i++) {
  hearts[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log("clicks works");
    var clicks = document.querySelectorAll(".like-counts");
    var arrayNumbers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++) {
      var clicks = clicks[i] + 1;
      arrayNumbers.push(clicks.innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-post__body">
  <footer class="blog-post__info blog-post__info--photo">
    <span class="heart-icon"><svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
            <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
          </svg></span>
    <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
    <span class="like-counts">356</span>
  </footer>
</div>
<div class="blog-post__body">
  <footer class="blog-post__info blog-post__info--photo">
    <span class="heart-icon"><svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
            <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
          </svg></span>
    <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
    <span class="like-counts">356</span>
  </footer>
</div>
```

I made something wrong in replacing innerHTML array. Can you please explain what I am doing wrong? (I would rather use plain javascript than jquery).

Comment: sorry, forgot to comment it in this editor (fixed)

Comment: I think the .innerHTML is in the wrong place. Move it to the previous line. Also avoid multiple variables with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What are you doing wrong:**

1. On a click you iterate over all ".like-counts"-elements, also over those that are not in a logical context of your clicked "os-list__icon" element
2. You increase all values by 1
3. You never use your arrayNumbers array

Here a example of what you might want:

HTML:

```
    <section name="like-component">
  <span class="heart-icon">A<svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
    <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
    </svg></span>
  <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
  <span class="like-counts">0</span>
</section>

<section name="like-component">
  <span class="heart-icon">A<svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
    <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
    </svg></span>
  <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
  <span class="like-counts">0</span>
</section>


<section name="like-component">
  <span class="heart-icon">A<svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
    <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
    </svg></span>
  <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
  <span class="like-counts">0</span>
</section>
```

JS:

```
let allLikeComponents = document.querySelectorAll('section[name="like-component"]')


allLikeComponents.forEach(function(aSingleLikeComponent){
  let heartIcon = aSingleLikeComponent.querySelector('.heart-icon')
  heartIcon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let likeCountsDiv = aSingleLikeComponent.querySelector('.like-counts')
    let content = likeCountsDiv.textContent;
    likeCountsDiv.textContent = (Number(content)+1);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course its much more logical realization than I was going to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Shortened**

Access the count **at** **once** for example with

```
var counts = document.querySelectorAll(".blog-post__body .like-counts")
```

Add to each element with

```
[].forEach.call(counts, count => ...)
```

and event.

**In total**

```js
var counts = document.querySelectorAll(".blog-post__body .like-counts");
[].forEach.call(counts, count => {
  count.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var n = +this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = n + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="blog-post__body">
  <footer class="blog-post__info blog-post__info--photo">
    <span class="heart-icon"><svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
        <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
      </svg></span>
    <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
    <span class="like-counts">356</span>
  </footer>
</div>
<div class="blog-post__body">
  <footer class="blog-post__info blog-post__info--photo">
    <span class="heart-icon"><svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
        <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
      </svg></span>
    <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
    <span class="like-counts">356</span>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

you need to get `span value using innerHTML` and `convert it to int`

```
parseInt(clicks[i].innerHTML)
```

```js
var hearts = document.getElementsByClassName("os-list__icon");
for (var i = 0; i < hearts.length; i++) {
  hearts[i].onclick = function() {
// console.log("clicks works");
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll(".like-counts");
var arrayNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++) {
  var click = parseInt(clicks[i].innerHTML) + 1;
  clicks[i].innerHTML = click;
  arrayNumbers.push(clicks[i].innerHTML);
  
}
console.log(arrayNumbers);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-post__body">
  <footer class="blog-post__info blog-post__info--photo">
    <span class="heart-icon"><svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
        <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
      </svg></span>
    <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
    <span class="like-counts">356</span>
  </footer>
</div>
<div class="blog-post__body">
  <footer class="blog-post__info blog-post__info--photo">
    <span class="heart-icon"><svg width="25" height="13" class="os-list__icon os-list__icon--apple">
        <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-heart"></use>
      </svg></span>
    <span class="like-text">Нравится:</span>
    <span class="like-counts">356</span>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: And click should change number just for corresponding span, if i understand requirement correctly?

Comment: I think that OP wanted something more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qqotm800/1/ (and not sure about need for array at all) ;)